# Style being ignored when ICollectionView refreshed

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a viewmodel which defines a `List<string>`. This is exposed using a public `ICollectionView`:

```
List<string> _items { get; } = new List<string>() { "Test item" };
public ICollectionView CollectionView { get; }
....
        CollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_items);
        CollectionView.Filter = FilterItems;
```

The `CollectionView` object also defines a `FilterItems` function to filter the list.

On the UI side I have a ListBox which defines a data template and binds to `CollectionView` and everything works as expected. I initially got these warnings for each list box item:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

But I eliminated them by adding a style to the window which applies to all `ListBoxItem`s:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

However, whenever I call `Refresh()` on `CollectionView`, the style doesn't seem to apply anymore, as the two warnings above come back for each list item! In fact, there are a couple of additional errors as well:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

What's happening here? Why is the style ignored when the collection is refreshed?

Oddly enough I can fix this by moving the style out of Window.Resource and putting it into Application.Resource in App.xaml but I don't understand why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These binding errors are harmless and handled internally so you can safely just ignore them, or suppress them. Please refer to the following link for more information.

**Resolving harmless binding errors in WPF:** https://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/resolving-un-harmful-binding-errors-in-wpf

You may also want to read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/42cd1554-de7a-473b-b977-ddbd6298b3d0/binding-error-when-using-compositecollection-for-menuitems?forum=wpf) thread on the MSDN forums.